# React Syntax Error. Unterminated Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react project, I am setting my news variable to the setNews state. I am passing news as a deconstructed prop so I can use the map method in my jsx. I am trying to nest some data fields from the API I am using but in doing so I get this error. I have tried making sure that I was not missing an additional curly brace, semi-colon, or parenthesis. I have commented out the div's but then the compiler says the map method should not have a period and have a comma instead. How can I fix this?

[Unterminated Regular Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLz4h.png)

[React code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqp5c.png)

Comment: Try putting a arrow function in your mapping

Comment: Thanks for the images but could you please copy and paste your code into your post please?

Comment: Please post code as text, not a link to a painting of it. Also make sure to properly indent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, please leave your code as text in your post, but in the meantime I can point you to your issue. There a couple of them actually.

1. You don't have the right number of closing curly braces. Notice that in your code you open them 3 times, but close them just 2.
2. In order to render properties from your `news` array, you need to enclose them in curly braces as well. Here is a working code:

```
function SearchResults() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {news.map(function (n) {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{n.title}</p>
            <p>{n.author}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And finally, and this is just a suggestion, you can use an arrow style function inside your map to shorten your code a bit. e.g.:

```
<div className="App">
      {news.map((n, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <p>{n.title}</p>
          <p>{n.author}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry for not posting the code incorrectly. As for the code, thank you! It did eliminate the previous issue but now I get an error that says "Cannot read property map 'of' undefined.

Comment: @DL89 That's an unrelated error and most likely has to do with not passing the `news` variable to `SearchResults` element.

Comment: @DL89 So if you need help with that one, you should accept this answer as the one that solved your problem and then post another question regarding the `undefined` issue.

Comment: Yeah, it helped me out a lot. Thanks again. I want to try to work on it from here and If I can't solve it after 30 mins or so then I will make a new post. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @DL89 No problem. We're always here to help. And I commend you for trying to solve that issue by yourself first.